# Why can't function access local variable in object declared outside

Tags: javascript

I was adding validation functions for my Node application, and want a custom message for the field I provide in that function. The issue is, some options need  to have a default values, and others I can pass as parameters.

```
let field = 'email';

let options = {
  'message': `${field} is required`
}

function validation(field, opt = options) {
  console.log(opt.message);
}

validation('password');
validation('confirm', {message: 'Confirm password is required'})
```

But in this case, the output is

```
"email is required"
"Confirm password is required"
```

While I want the output to be

```
"password is required"
"Confirm password is required"
```

I also want to know how Javascript works for this code. How it is accessing all the stuff and how to get the required output.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? *(Because from the code snippet you provided I strongly presume you didn't)*

Comment: Perhaps to be a bit more specific about my *"angry"* comment up there, I'm asking because you are **assigning inside a function declaration, due to which most linters will throw a warning for!**

Comment: @rawrplus that is a default parameter. Learn JS yourself before you try to teach others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you just create `option` object and you create it with `message` field = "email is required". And you never change it's value. As an alternative you may generate object each time you want it to be parametrized:

```
const field = 'email';

const getOptions = (field) => ({
  'message': `${field} is required`
});

function validation(field, opt) {
  opt = opt || getOptions(field);
  console.log(opt.message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
let field = 'email';

let options = {
  'message': `${field} is required`
}
```

This assigns `options.message` with the current value of `field`. Since you never changes its value, you get `"email is required"`. The parameter named `field` in `function validation(field, opt = options)` is a different variable than the global one with the same name. And its value has no affect on the value of `options.message` because that assignment was already executed before the function was ever called.

Manipulating global objects is considered poor programming. Instead, you can create the object inside the function:

```
function validation(field) {
    let opt = {
      'message': `${field} is required`
    }

      console.log(opt.message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   message:`${field} is required`
```

Is the same as:

```
 message: field + " is required"
```

which directly looks up `field` and results in:

```
 message: "email is required"
```

To evaluate later you have to use a function that you pass the field name in which then returns the message:

```
 const options = {
   message: field => `${field} is required`,
 }

 function validation(field, opt = options) {
   const msg = typeof opt.message === "function" ? opt.message(field) : opt.message;
   console.log(msg);
 }

 validation('password');
 validation('confirm', {message: 'Confirm password is required'})
```